# RecyclerView not displaying List items - FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My List doesn't seem to be getting initialised and I'm not really sure what I should be doing here, everytime I run I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alarmclockproject, PID: 13493
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.alarmclockproject.fragments.AlarmListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlarmListAdapter.kt:27)
```

Removing the notifyDataSetChanged() stops the fatal crash, but then shows no alarms on fragment, despite multiple being in the database ( checked using DB Browser )

Here is my Adapter:

```
class AlarmListAdapter() :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private var alarmList: List<Alarm> = ArrayList()


class ViewHolder(binding: FragmentHomeBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = alarmList[position]
    holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_alarm_time).text =
        "${currentItem.hour}:${currentItem.minute}"
    //holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_repeat_days)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return alarmList.size
}

fun setData(alarm: List<Alarm>){
    this.alarmList = alarm
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

}
```

My HomeFragment where the recycler view is displayed:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
private lateinit var alarmViewModel: AlarmViewModel


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    // RecyclerView
    val adapter = AlarmListAdapter()
    val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    //ViewModel
    alarmViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AlarmViewModel::class.java)
    alarmViewModel.readAlarmData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { alarm ->
        adapter.setData(alarm)
    })

    binding.btnAddAlarm.setOnClickListener{
        Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_newAlarmFragment)
    }
    return binding.root
}
}
```

and it's layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_next_alarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="11:11"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_alarm"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="446dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_add_alarm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_next_alarm" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
class AlarmViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

val readAlarmData: LiveData<List<Alarm>>
private val repository: AlarmRepository

init {
    val alarmDao = AlarmsDatabase.getDatabase(application).alarmDao()
    repository = AlarmRepository(alarmDao)
    readAlarmData = repository.readAlarmData
}

fun addAlarm(alarm: Alarm) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.addAlarm(alarm)
    }
}
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface AlarmDao {

@Insert()
suspend fun addAlarm(alarm: Alarm)

@Query("SELECT * FROM alarm_table ORDER BY  id ASC")
fun readAlarmData(): LiveData<List<Alarm>>

@Update
fun updateAlarm(alarm: Alarm)
}
```

and the Alarm Class:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "alarm_table")
data class Alarm (
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int,
val hour: Int,
val minute: Int,
val repeat: Boolean
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in `onCreateViewHolder()` is causing the crash:

> val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))

You are inflating the `FragmentHomeBinding`, which has no `TextView` with id *R.id.tv_alarm_time*. Use that of the `RecyclerView` item instead.

Comment: How do I set the binding from the RecyclerView? Everthing I have found online uses the older methods and I can't find anything for binding.

Comment: @Joe Pleavin - At least you have view binding activated in your app (or else there would be no FragmentHomeBinding). What is the name of the layout file for the RecyclerView item? The Binding name is similar, just in camel case and with "Binding" at the end

Comment: i wish I had just asked earlier instead of sitting here trying to figure it out for hours. Your answer worked straight away, dumb mistake I won't repeat, thanks so much!

Comment: @JoePleavin - you're very welcome :) And don't regret the time you've spent trying to figure out what was wrong - in the long run the experience will make you  a better developer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: fyi the guide on [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Hammer! thanks so much!